# Cross platform ServiceStack Authentication

Tags: authentication, servicestack

What is the best way to architect the following solution for authentication?

I have a standalone (not integrated with MVC) ServiceStack REST service layer. This service is the entry point to all my data. No data is stored on the client.

I have multiple clients (ASP.Net MVC 4 site, MonoTouch app, MonoDroid app, Silverlight app, MonoMac app, etc).

I would like to provide authentication (Facebook, Twitter, etc) at the service level, including storing the users in the MongoDBAuthRepository, but allow the clients to provide the login UI (do I want this?). For example, for the MVC site, I'd like to integrate the remote ServiceStack authentication service (including Facebook, Twitter), with MVC's authentication system.  It seems like the actual authentication should occur on the service side, but the client side needs to hold on to the authentication response.

I've read the wiki, looked at SocialBootstrap, and read the forum, but I'm still confused as to how this is supposed to work in a distributed way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OAuth options like Twitter + Facebook your authentication should happen in a browser as they each require redirections from their respected auth provider to capture trusted verification from each user. Some mobile apps do this by embedding a browser widget for Twitter + FB Auth.

Once a user is authenticated with Twitter + Facebook and Credentials in the same authenticated session, [ServiceStack's AuthProviders](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) automatically merges all Auth info into the same account. So later you will be able to login with 1 auth provider but get access to info available on all 3. The [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) project provides an example of this.

Comment: The part I'm missing is, if I do the FB/Twitter auth in the browser (and consequently, on the client (mvc/mobile/etc)) side, how do I pass that auth to the ServiceStack remote service?

Comment: The ServiceClient just needs to specify the `ss-pid` cookie which can be implicitly assigned by using BasicAuth/DigestAuth or explicitly assigned with a direct call the the `/auth/*` service. Otherwise you can physically add the cookie to the ServiceClient, its just a base62 encoded AuthSessionId guid

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to get this to work, but I think I'm *still* missing something. The user logs in to twitter/facebook on the phone, and then tries to register with my ServiceStack service or access a service that requires auth. What Auth provider on service? What parameters to pass? What password to set?   http://imageshack.us/a/img84/5415/servicestackoauthfromcl.png http://imageshack.us/a/img607/5415/servicestackoauthfromcl.png

Comment: i have the same situation as Rob and am confused as well. if i do the oauth with twitter/fb on the client (via javascript for example), then what do i need to add to my C# client to pass along those credentials in order to access a secure service?

Comment: Did you have more information about these questions for two years? I am also trying to authenticate my mobile application with my servicestack website but I am lost about the process...