# ServiceStack Facebook/OAuth for Mobile Apps

Tags: authentication, oauth, servicestack

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the workflow of Facebook/Twitter/OAuth authentication within ServiceStack with regards to native mobile apps.

This is piggybacking off of [Cross platform ServiceStack Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675009), which tries to answer it, but doesn't really explain everything that was asked.

I understand that the native apps have to authenticate with FB/Twitter directly via browser. How then do you go about getting all those session bits together to register a new user or reconcile an existing user? I get that you can use the AuthProviders to merge all the Auth-specific data into a single user record, but if you are outside of ServiceStack when you get the auth response from FB/Twitter, what do you then call to get Servicestack to merge those session bits? Is there an intended next step that I'm not seeing?